# Cannot put object in Map

Tags: java, dictionary, put

I have a class 'Message' with the following fields:

```
private String text;
private String from;
private String to;
```

A class 'User' with the following fields:

```
private String name;
private String surname;
private int age;
```

and a class 'ChatService', that uses a `Map`

```
private Map<User, ArrayList<Message>> sourceOfMessage = new HashMap<>();
```

and implements a method called 'write'

```
public void write(User sender, User receiver, String message) {

        Message message1 = new Message(message, sender.getName(), receiver.getName());

        sourceOfMessage.put(sender,message1);
        sourceOfMessage.put(receiver,message1);

        }
```

in the Main class I do the following:

```
User ivan = new User("Ivan", "Mad", 23);
User igor = new User("Igor", "Bil", 25);
ChatService chat = new ChatService();
chat.write(ivan, igor, "Hello");
```

My question is: why does the map (`sourceOfMessage`) contains two keys and no values?

Comment: `private Map<User, ArrayList<Message>> sourceOfMessage = new HashMap<>();` You are trying to put in a message into the Map not a ArrayList of messages. try `private Map<User, Message> sourceOfMessage = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: **By the way**, I see that until now you didn't accept any answer in questions you have asked so far. **You should accept an answer if it solves your problem.** By clicking tick below vote numbers in one of the answers on the left

Comment: Not to mention that you do it mention implementing the hashCode and equals methods in User - without them, HashMap doesn’t work

Answer (score 1):

The map values must be `ArrayList<Message>` but you are putting just `Message`. This code shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Map<User, ArrayList<Message>> sourceOfMessage
```

The value is of type `ArrayList`, not `Message`.

```
sourceOfMessage.put(sender,message1);
```

You use `put` method of map, so you map `sender` which is key to `message1` which is value and is of type `Message`.

After all, you pass incompatible types between them.